# How to read PUT and DELETE request using codeigniter framework?

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

I am creating an API server using codeigniter framework and I was wondering if it is possible to read PUT and DELETE requests from any client side form submissions?

The user guide doesn't explain much regarding this.

Comment: use this `$this->input->method();`

Answer (score 1):

You can try to detect the method type first and seperate the different cases:

```
switch($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']){
   case 'GET':

      ...
      break;
   case 'POST':

      ...
      break;
   case 'PUT':

      ...
      break;
   case 'DELETE':

      ...
      break;
   default:
      echo "Unknown Request.";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The HTML standard [does not support](https://www.w3.org/TR/2012/CR-html5-20121217/forms.html#attr-fs-method) `PUT` inside the `<form method="">` attribute and also browser doesn't support it. Browsers don't generally support methods other than GET and POST in HTML forms. if you put anything else other than `POST` or `GET` it should be sent as a GET request according to specification.

Use hidden `method` field in your form and put the actual HTTP.Use [this library](https://github.com/chriskacerguis/codeigniter-restserver)

Answer (score 0):

In codeigniter you can get values of PUT or DELETE with this :  $this->input->raw_input_stream; and you can split the string url into array and put the values of array into object with this methode set_array() you must to create this method in model to set each value to right attribute
and you can use this code by customize it with your project :

```js
        $method = $this->input->server('REQUEST_METHOD');
    if($method === 'PUT')
    {
        $this->input->raw_input_stream;

        $input_data = $this->input->raw_input_stream;
        
        $exploded = array();
        parse_str($input_data, $exploded);
        $daman = new damancom_model();
        $daman->set_array($exploded);
        $daman->ID = $exploded["ID"];
        $daman->edit_damancom();
    }
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Codeigniter 3

If you want to utilize the PUT, DELETE, PATCH or other exotic request methods, they can only be accessed via a special input stream, that can only be read once.

See documentation...

https://codeigniter.com/userguide3/libraries/input.html#using-the-php-input-stream

Make sure your request has...

`Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded`

Also, if sending inputs you can grab them via input_stream() method like this...

`$this->input->input_stream('user_id');`

(i.e. change user_id to which ever input name you are using on form)